# Searching SharePoint site with Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, sharepoint

Every week, I manually backup recent versions of the files on my group's SharePoint site. I open the library in Windows Explorer, search for all files modified in the past week, then copy and paste them to a network location. We need this process because our SharePoint site has a quota that we would easily meet if we had unlimited versions, so we keep a history of older versions on the network.

Recently I got an upgrade to my work computer and I am unable to search the site using Windows Explorer. When I run the search for files modified in the last week no results are returned. If I run a search with no criteria on the file library, all the files are found but the "modified on" field is blank. So the search results only have the file and type fields. The new computer has Windows XP, just like the old one did.

I hope this makes sense. Does anyone have any clue what the problem could be? I'd be happy to provide more info if necessary. It's bugging me to no end and I'm not even sure where to begin looking - it's either a trivial issue or a very obscure one.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that my Web Client service was constantly in a stopping state for some reason. It probably had to do with one of my network places: I followed the [instructions here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912152/en-us) and then I used Process Explorer to stop the service (so I wouldn't have to restart my computer). Then the service started and search began working again.